# How to get insert data after using function store then pass it to blade?

Tags: laravel

UPDATE i want to pass session variable value to blade variable to store its value for if condition

I want to pass controller variable value to blade variable

Controller

```
return back()->with('pass',$pass);
```

Blade

** Example value 12

```
{{(session()->get("pass",null)}}
```

I want to pass to blade variable to store the value of session variable pass

```
@php
$i = {{(session()->get("pass")}}
@endphp
```

***Found Solution Thank you 
Something like this***

```
@php
    $i = session()->get("pass", 1) 
@endphp

{{$i}}
```

Comment: $item->id will give you id after save being called

Comment: Sidenote: Watch you quotes; you have a `"` followed by a `'` in your HTML

Comment: `{{(session()->get("pass",null)}}` is a syntax error; you've got an opening `(` without a closing one... `{{ session()->get("pass",null) }}`, and you don't use `{{ }}` inside an `@php ... @endphp` block.

Comment: @TimLewis thank you sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `->with()` on `back()` sets values into `session()`; it doesn't make them directly available as a variable. If you want to access a value like that, you need to check `session()`:

```
{{ session()->get("pass", null) }}
```

What this does is attempts to access the value, and if it can't find anything, simply outputs `null`. Note that this value is only available for 1 request, and `session()->get("pass")` will be `null` for any refreshes/new requests.